# using secure social in single page app

Tags: playframework, securesocial

I am developing a simple ecommerce kind of website where only some actions require authentication, like in case of writing reviews for products.

For example when review is clicked login page is loaded as single page app but when logged in with UsernamePasswordProvider/Facebook with the login page from secure social the full page is loading.

Is there a simple way to make it as single page app than to fork securesocial and myself modifying all the calls as ajax/single page app calls.

Comment: I'm wanting to know the same. Currently I haven't found a way, so I'm modifying all the standard calls (as you suggested). It's not ideal, but at the same time it's not too hard to do.

Answer (score 0):

Latest changes in master let you authenticate users using an API. See this question for further details: [Expose Play Framework rest calls secured via securesocial to mobile app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23868797/expose-play-framework-rest-calls-secured-via-securesocial-to-mobile-app).