# Posting a file on a Play application using cURL

Tags: curl, playframework, playframework-2.0

I need to upload a file via command line on a Play application I've written. 
The problem is that I need some authentication (I used the `Secured` machinery described in the tutorial), and when I use the cURL command:

```
curl -i -F name=test -F filedata=@localfile.jpg http://example.org/upload
```

the application throws a NullPointerException when it tries to verify if the user has the privileges to perform the upload.

I managed to log in using cURL (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23868797/expose-play-framework-rest-calls-secured-via-securesocial-to-mobile-app/23893048#23893048)):

```
curl -i --data "email=some.email@address.com&password=somepassword"  http://example.org/login
```

and I got the answer:

```
 HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
 Location: /
 Set-Cookie: PLAY_SESSION="891c38b687bf198d31af51cc61647f8339d30657-email=some.email%40address.com"; Path=/; HTTPOnly
 Content-Length: 0
```

Now, how can I use this cookie to post my file?

**Some code, since you asked**

```
public class Secured extends Security.Authenticator {

    @Override
    public String getUsername(Context ctx) {
        return ctx.session().get("email");
    }

    @Override
    public Result onUnauthorized(Context ctx) {
        return redirect(routes.Application.login());
    }

    public static boolean isReadOnly() {
     return UserType.READ_ONLY.equals(User.find.where().eq("email",Context.current().request().username()).findUnique().userType);
    }
}



public class Upload extends Controller {

    public static Result upload(String mode) throws IOException {
        if(!Secured.isReadOnly()) {

              (Handle the form to upload the file)            

        } else {
             return controllers.Utils.generalForbidden();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the code of the controller that handle the request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the cookie that you get from your login request to a file called "cookie.jar" via

```
curl -c cookie.jar -i --data "email=some.email@address.com&password=somepassword"  http://example.org/login
```

In order to use the cookie, just do

```
 curl -b cookie.jar http://example.org/your_endpoint
```