# Use SecueSocial for PlayFramework >2.3 with UserPasswordProvider and REST (stateless token auth)

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.4, securesocial

After lots of research i still wonder how to use SecureSocial with the UsernamePasswordProvider via REST. I need to get an auth token from SecureSocial after login so that i can put this token in the X-Auth-Header for future requests to secured actions in a stateless manner.

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23893048/2310624) I'm now able to login with curl but the answer from the server is empty (instead of the expected access token).

I'm using SecureSocial 3.0-M4 and PlayFramework 2.4 with Java. Unfortunately the docs for SecureSocial 3.0-M4 are not up to date, so I have no idea if this version supports such a scenario.

Is there a possibility to get SecureSocial working with X-Auth-Tokens? Does SecureSocial provide such functionality?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you really need to use secure social? that project is essentially abandoned and you're going to face serious issues as soon as you want to migrate to a current play version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my question:

SecureSocial provides an interface for token based authentication!

The problem was that I sent the request to /authenticate that is used for cookie based authentication instead of sending to /api/authenticate as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23893048/2310624).